# python can't import module when running a file, but can import the module in interactive shell

Tags: python

I got a strange problem.

`filegetter` is a module developed by someone else and installed with `python setup.py install`.

Here is a test file.

```
#instance.py
import filegetter
```

when I run

```
/home/ynx/miniconda3/bin/python /home/ynx/notebook/instance.py
```

it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ynx/notebook/instance.py", line 2, in <module>
    import filegetter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filegetter'
```

But if I run an interactive shell: python

```
>>> import filegetter
>>>
```

It works.
I am sure the same python bin is used by check which, why and how can I import it in the file mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem with `sys.path`. When you run the Python shell, the path to the current directory is added to `sys.path`, making modules in this directory `import`-able. To make a module available to all of your Python programs, store it in the user site directory, which you can find with

```
$ python -m site --user-site
```

Alternatively, place a script called `usercustomize.py` in the user site directory, which manually adds paths to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to')
```

where the full path of `filegetter.py` would be `/path/to/filegetter.py`

Comment: Oh... there is directory call `filegetter` I ignored, the module was never installed...

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by the site directory not being found.
For simplicity i prefer to add it in the PATH system variable.
Find the path to the site-packages directory:

```
python -m site --user-site     #  /home/zorro/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

Add it to your PATH:
For linux, can be added to your shell profile file,

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/YOU/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

If not persistent you can do:

```
echo 'PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/YOU/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' >> ~/.bashrc
```

For Windows add it from PATH and environment variables.